# How to connect Flyway running in a Docker container to a database running in a Docker container?

Tags: sql-server, docker, flyway

We use Microsoft SQL Server as database and Flyway for managing it. Now I'd like to test Flyway scripts by starting SQL Server in Docker and Flyway in my own Docker container that contains all the configuration and all the Flyway database scripts (migrations).

As far as I know, it's not possible to use environment variables within Flyway configuration files. Ideally, this would be possible:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://${MSSQL_SERVICE_HOST}:${MSSQL_SERVICE_PORT};databaseName=testing_pp
flyway.user=testing_pp
flyway.password=${MSSQL_SERVICE_PASSWORD}
```

In fact, I need to know the best strategy for both standalone Docker and OpenShift. I'm pretty new to both...

Is there a way to inject the IP address and the port from one running Docker container to another? One that doesn't involve Docker Compose? And what would be the right way to do it in OpenShift? I know that the pods there get the hosts and ports from all running pods as environment variables (see my hypothetic solution). But these variables aren't resolved, it doesn't solve my problem.

How are you doing such tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting you right, the question is about how to connect two docker containers without `docker-compose`. In fact `docker-compose` doesnt add a lot in these terms - it just automates several steps.

To connect containers, you have to:

1. Create new user-defined bridge network (done once): `docker network create foo`
2. Connect both containers to this network with `--network=foo` startup option
3. Specify container names instead of autogenerated with `--name=xyz`
4. Use these names instead of IP addressed in your connection strings.

   ```
   docker network create foo
   docker run -d --rm --name=my-database --network=foo <SQLServerImageName>
   docker run -d --rm --name=my-flyway --network=foo <FlyWayImageName>
   ```

Now you can connect from Flyway to SQL with `server=my-database`

Comment: Thanks, that solves one part of the equation. The other one is getting that name into Flyway using an environment variable.

Comment: `docker run -d --rm -e "SQL_SERVER=my-database" --name=my-flyway --network=foo <FlyWayImageName>`

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting... I tested everything with a shell script. It seems like Flyway (which I don't start in detached mode, since it's a one-off thing) doesn't see the network:

    Flyway Community Edition 5.0.7 by Boxfuse

    ERROR:
    Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:sqlserver://flyway:1433;databaseName=etrademark) for user 'etrademark': The TCP/IP connection to the host flyway, port 1433 has failed. Error: "flyway. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port."

Comment: Do you know how I could check whether the container know the domain name?

Comment: My mistake was that I used the network name as domain name to connect to. I need to use the Docker name, in this case `my-database` in my JDBC connection string.